# pro tinkering for html select box look-alike but with extra features

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, user-interface

This could be an fun question. I'm planning to make a select box that looks like normal html at first, but when you open it there will be two exciting things:

1. The box will contain 2 different text-aligns making two neat rows.(see picture)
2. At the end of each line of the list item contained in the box, there will be a like/dislike button system.(see picture)

[image: *picture*]

Some of you already know where this is going, I'll need to make the thing like you'd make any such menu in GUI programming. I assume some object oriented Javascript programming?

(I'm looking for technical details as I'm novice at Javascript and jQuery(but not at programming), I'm basically interested in info about transferring such a pseudocode construct into Javascript/jQuery or another more usable framework if really need be. I'm also perfectly aware that I'm normally not going to be using any actual html in this GUI.)

So my question is, how should I set out to do this according to you?

Comment: Here's something I started, one time: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wDSbT/2/).

Comment: Quite fun =) But yet again html, perhaps I'm the one in the wrong here but isn't there a way to make GUI's in javascript which aren't based on html and css? I think this would be way simpler than trying to add 2 columns and 3 buttons into each <li> of a list element in html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to modify a normal `select` element to achieve this, you will have to

- Create a proxy-pro-select-element and hide the original one.
- Copy option elements and create equivalent one in your proxy
- You will have to also keep both selects in sync.

Once you have that you can do anything in your proxy-pro-select-element, simplest would be to on click show a table with select able rows, with table it would be very easy to align all columns.

Technical details:

- Read how to implement a [jQuery plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring)
- In your plugin's `init` loop through options in target `select` and create corresponding rows in a div say `dropdown`, hide original select and replace it with your control which will be a `select-div`
- onclick on select-div, show dropdown div after re-positioning correctly

See code like [this](https://github.com/sparkbox/Custom-Selectbox/blob/master/js/jquery.sparkbox-select.js) and modify

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was thinking(see html-look alike part of my tittle), and perhaps I can even stream the MySQL data directly into the pro select box. 

But I'm kinda more interested in technical details. I'll edit my question to make this clear.

Comment: @I have added a few details, but I am not sure what more I can add unless you start implementing and ask more questions, or do you want me to implement it? :)

Comment: No certainly not, though it would save me time, I prefer to do my own work and coding =P but thanks for sarcastically suggesting anyway ;) Though I'd prefer to just code the thing without any actual html, I'll happily look into your method.

Comment: I eventually made a dummy select element resized to the div width. I used jQuery .css for the width and there was no need to have two instances of the same data to keep in sync, just one dummy select and one div.

Comment: @happy but if you are not using select, normal form submission won't work

Comment: as the word is selected by the user it'll be placed in a form by jQuery

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish something similar to this with jQuery and jQuery UI comboboxing, http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox

And then modify _renderItem to change the layout of results in the dropdown. You can search for the following in the view source:

```
input.data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem
```

However, I would try to avoid having like/dislike buttons in a combo box because it goes against normal web conventions.

Comment: Wait, are you saying I can implement 2 text aligns, both to the left, with a space in between, plus 3 buttons with hoover effects and all this on one single line, on every single line of a select box list, using html, css and some javascript? It just sounds highly implausible...

Comment: Not that I'm not willing to have a look at it ofc, but highly skeptic about it